# Проблема с кодировкой письма

Tags: php, email, utf-8

Есть скрипт отправки, как сделать, чтоб письма приходили с нормальной кодировкой на почту?

```
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail = "vercanov.maksim@mail.ru";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$name = check_input($_POST['inputName'], "Your Name");
$email = check_input($_POST['inputEmail'], "Your E-mail Address");
$num = check_input($_POST['inputNum'], "Your Number");

/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("Invalid e-mail address");
}
/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */

$subject = "Тема";
$num = "

Текст письма:

Мое имя: $name
Мой Email: $email
Мой телефон: $num
";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $num);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: http://testpage.com');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html>
<body>

<p>Please correct the following error:</p>
<strong><?php echo $myError; ?></strong>
<p>Hit the back button and try again</p>

</body>
</html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно явно задать в параметрах функции mail() кодировку для сообщения. Это четвертый параметр функции mail(), [исчерпывающий пример здесь.](http://www.php.su/mail)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sendsubj = "Тест заявка";
$sendsubj = '=?utf-8?B?' . base64_encode($sendsubj) . '?=';
mail($sendto, $sendsubj, $sendbody, $sendheaders)
```